# How to scrape dynamic website created on toggle button with python?

Tags: python, selenium, dynamic, web-scraping

I want to scrape the table website layout from www.crackwatch.com
When you click the toggle button on the top right on the site, it changes the layout to the table form, which has more games history listed... and I want to scrape every game in there...

the problem is, how do I get to download the the table format layout website? as it seems, the site is being generated dynamically when I click the button and therefore I have no website adress or similar to scrape for the elements...

do I have to use Selenium or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use two Python libraries in conjunction: BeautifulSoup and Selenium

If the content is loaded to the table **after** clicking on the toggle button, then this will require you to use Selenium and pass driver.page_source to BeautifulSoup, since the content is created dynamically inside of the website and not included in the original source HTML (this would be the most intuitive implementation IMO):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find_all('tbody', {'id': 'games-table-adder'})

for row in table:

    #Extract the information that you are interested in here
```

Apologies if this is not fully functional, cannot test this at work with firewalls.

However, if the table is included in the original source HTML, then you can just access this table by passing the URL of the website to Python's requests library and then passing that to BeautifulSoup similar to above:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

header = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5'}

link = 'insert your link here'

url  = requests.get(link, headers = header).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
```

Hopefully this gets you started.

Comment: thanks, I think its helpful at least, I cannot find the "games-table-adder" in normal html , so I guess I have to go into Selenium a bit first...

Comment: try right-clicking on the elements you are interested in pulling and click 'Inspect Element'

Comment: ok and how can I inspect the dynamic elements? I mean which element is it and how can I see what it's doing?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in getting back to you. As far as inspecting the dynamic elements, you should be able to still right-click on the elements you are interested in scraping from your normal browser, then pass these elements to BeautifulSoup after accessing the webpage via Selenium